# using inline css in spfx webpart

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

I am trying use inline css in html content but it shows the error you see in the picture below;
[image]

How can I use inline css in spfx webpart ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it as below:

```
style={{"color" : "black"}}
```

If you want multiple attributes, try comma separated values as below:

```
style={{"color":"black","font-family":"verdana","font-size":"1.4rem"}}
```